# How to run a function when an Express server starts up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't seem to figure out how to get my express server to run a simple function when the server starts up. Where is the appropriate place to call a function to run on server startup, and the proper syntax?

I have the function in my routes file as `exports.myFunction = function() { code here};`

I've tried sticking it in the app.configure block as routes.myFunction. I've tried changing it in routes to just be `myfunction() { code}`, then calling it in the configure block as `routes.myfunction()`, no luck there either. The function needs to stay in the file containing my routes since it alters some global variables there.

I know it's some stupidly simple syntax thing, but I can't seem to find any hints [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) or on google. Much thanks for any help!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use this event:

```
app.on('listening', function () {
    // server ready to accept connections here
});
```

To be honest `app` returned by express.createServer() is just http.Server, so everything described in [nodejs docs related to http.Server](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.0/api/http.html#http.Server) make sense for express and [railwayjs](http://railwayjs.com/).

Comment: It does not work for me. I think it's related to the fact that the `www` file from the generator already has a `listening` event?

Answer (score 18):

I would keep it simple. In the module where you call `app.listen(port)`, just call your startup function right before (or after) that. If you need that function to reside in a separate module full of other routes, just export it so your main `server.js` module can invoke it on startup. If you are still not satisfied with that, consider maybe binding an event listener somewhere in express/connect, although I'm not sure an explicit "startup" event is emitted.

In server.js (or whatever module you start your express server), do this:

```
var myRoutes = require("./myroutes");
var app = express.createServer();
...
app.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", function() {
  myRoutes.myFunction();
});
```

You can also bind to the "listening" event as @Anatoly says. The [docs for the listening event are here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.13/api/net.html#net_event_listening).

Comment: hmm, still no luck. I'm not getting any indication that the function is actually being run, but no error either. =/

Comment: What do you mean by "export it so your main server.js module can invoke it on startup"? Forgive me for I'm new with express/javascript