# Express JS Calling route when application start

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking for the best way to call a route (or a function) when my express js application starts.

Typically I would like to call a route's method directly from my `app.js` like this when I run node `./app.js`

```
//app.js
var teams = require('./routes/teams');
app.use('/teams', teams);

server.listen(server_port, function(){
  teams.foo() // <- this is what I would like to call when runing node ./app.js
});
```

Where teams is a route

```
//routes/teams.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var request = require('request');

router.get('/foo', function(req, res, next) {   
    foo()
  res.json({'result':'check foo teams'});
});

function foo(){
    //....
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a function when an Express server starts up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781538/how-to-run-a-function-when-an-express-server-starts-up)

Comment: Are you tying to run code at startup or direct people to a default route?

Comment: @MindlessRouse Yes I try to run code at startup. I edited my question.

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal no because the question is about how to call the function and not where to call.

Comment: What all have you tried? What worked, what didn't?

Comment: Well, I tried a lot of stuffs. Last one was `teams.foo()` but it return `undefined`